# How to get posts from network blog

Tags: posts, functions, multisite, ajax

So I have function that gets posts with URL(id) (ajax stuff). It works but now I would like also fetch posts from other blogs in my network. I'm baffled how can I achieve this? Do I have to know the blog ID too somehow? So now it pass to my function the URL and with get_blog_id_from_url I get ID of the post and fetch all data and pass it via JSON back to fronded. But if I pass url of some of network blog, it doesn't know how fetch post data from that post.

EDIT: here is the function:

```
function my_query(){
  $url = $_POST['url'];

  $rsp_post = array();

  $post_id = url_to_postid( $url );

  global $post;
  $post = get_post( $post_id );

  $rsp_post[] = array(
    'post_title' => $post->post_title,
    'post_date' => $post->post_date
  );
  print json_encode( $rsp_post );

  exit;
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the function that gets your posts. If you haven't seen them yet, have a look at [`switch_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) and [`restore_current_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/restore_current_blog).

Comment: Ok i will add soon the function. But how can I switch to blog when I don't know the blog id?

Comment: Added the current function

Comment: You mentioned in your question [`get_blog_id_from_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_id_from_url) -- that's what I'd use to get the blog ID (ie, `get_blog_id_from_url( 'example.com', '/blog1/' );`).

Comment: Yes that could work. But what if the current blog is the main blog that doesn't have the blogN part in example.com/blogN?